# Unable to "extract as method/function" in VSCode (c/c++)

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

How do you use refactoring to extract a section of code as a method in VSCode?

I've tried the popular extensions and followed the link below but have not been able to do this simple refactor. Or is it not supported for c/c++?

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/refactoring#_refactoring-actions

Comment: what do you mean with "have not been able to do this"?  is there no option to do it or does it not have any effect?

Comment: I also don't see code actions, even when manually invoking with `Ctrl + .`. Can you list your active extensions? My VSCode version is 1.72.2

Comment: It is not an option and I would like to know how to get it in my vscode. There is an article showing it works in the link but I can't get it to show.